# Что значит for(int x : vector)

Tags: c++, vector, for

Недавно изучаю c++ по книге Страуструпа , и дошел до векторов, здесь в пример приведён код для прохода по всем элементам вектора

```
vector<int> v = { 5,7,9,4,6,8 };
for (int x : v)
    cout << x << endl;
```

но мне не понятно что делает вот это условие:`for(int x : v)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Range-based for-loop появился в языке начиная с С++11.

По определению, в данном конкретном случае (для `v` типа `std::vector<int>`) запись

```
for (int x : v)
  cout << x << endl;
```

эквивалентна

```
vector<int>::iterator b = v.begin();
vector<int>::iterator e = v.end();
for (; b != e; ++b)
{
  int x = *b;
  cout << x << endl;
}
```

---

В общем случае цикл вида

```
for ( decl-x : v ) 
  // тело цикла
```

(где `decl-x` - это объявление), интерпретируется как

```
{
  auto b = /* начало v */;
  auto e = /* конец v */;
  for (; b != e; ++b) 
  {
    decl-x = *b;
    // тело исходного цикла
  }
}
```

А "начало `v`" и "конец `v`" определяются в зависимости от типа `v`:

1. Если `v` - это массив размера `n`, то "начало" и "конец" - это просто `v` и `v + n`.
2. Для объекта класс-типа `v` с членами `begin` и `end` (оба должны присутствовать) "начало" и "конец" - это результаты вызовов `v.begin()` и `v.end()`.
3. Для всего остального "начало" и "конец" - это результаты вызовов `begin(v)` и `end(v)`, где имена `begin` и `end` ищутся только в ассоциированных с `v` пространствах имен

---

Некоторыми следствиями такой спецификации являются:

1. Конец итерируемого диапазона запоминается до начала цикла, т.е. попытки расширения/сужения/переаллокации диапазона в процессе работы цикла не повлияют на запомненное значение и, в общем случае, ни к чему хорошему не приведут.
2. Невозможно преопределить поведение для встроенных массивов путем перегрузки функций `begin` и `end` - эти функции будут просто проигнорированы.
3. По аналогичной причине невозможно "снаружи" преопределить поведение для классов, у которых уже есть свои внутренние `begin` и `end`.
4. Для типов, с которыми используются внешние `begin` и `end`, эти `begin` и `end` должны быть объявлены  непосредственно в ассоциированных пространствах имен. Объявленные в охватывающих пространствах имен `begin` и `end` найдены не будут

   ```
   namespace N { struct S {}; }

   int *begin(N::S &s) { return 0; }
   int *end(N::S &s) { return 0; }

   int main() {
     N::S s;
     for (int x : s) // Ошибка - нет `begin` и `end`
       {}
   }
   ```

Comment: Скорее уж `auto b = begin(v);`, потому как цикл по диапазону применим и к массивам, у которых, понятно, функции-члена `begin()` (да и `end()`) нет...

Comment: @Harry: Но "по-определению" не так. Я шел [почти] строго по тексту стандарта, где делается ветвление по типу аргумента: 1) обычный массив, 2) класс с `begin` и `end`, 3) все остальное. Что характерно, с массивами НЕ используется `std::begin` и `std::end`, а явно используется `array` и `array + size`. А для `std::vector` срабатывает второй пункт, т.е. напрямую используется `v.begin()` и `v.end()`, тез посредства `std::begin` и `std::end`. Отдельностоящие `begin` и `end` выходят на сцену только в пункте 3.

Comment: Очевидно это сделано так для того, чтобы *не дать* вам перегрузить `begin` и `end` для обычного массива. То есть перегружать вы можете сколько угодно, но range-based for для обычного массива обязан *иногрировать* ваши перегрузки (!). Аналогично для классов, у который есть свои члены `begin` и `end`. То есть дело обстоит скорее *наоборот* - range-based for изо всех сил старается НЕ пользоваться внешними `begin` и `end`. К ним он обращается только когда все остальные возможности уже исчерпаны.

Comment: @Harry,  Ну да, но  принципиально для автора вопроса важен смысль

Comment: @AnT: Ого, круто, не знал о таком хитром поведении. Может быть, имеет смысл внести в ответ в качестве дополнительной информации?

Answer (score 2):

Цикл `for` по диапазону. Такой "синтаксический сахар"

```
for(int x : v)
```

Переменная `x` поочередно принимает все значения из вектора (и не только вектора - это может быть другой стандартный контейнер или массив).