# Python в C++. Как можно написать оператор in

Tags: python, c++

В Python очень часто используется оператор in, мне в C++ также нужен данный оператор для перебора значений, то есть если на Python

```
for (i in abc):
```

Как это можно реализовать на C++
Я как-то сталкивался с похожим оператором, в котором испоьзовалось двоеточие, но найти не могу, так как в коде использовал другой метод.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вы имеете в виду эту запись:

```
for (auto item : container)
    // ...
```

Как я помню, все STL контейнеры поддерживают ее.

[Смежный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925148/c-proper-way-to-iterate-over-stl-containers), в котором ответ пользователя Girish Rao поясняет приведенную выше запись.

[STL containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)

Answer (score 1):

Это называется «Range-based for loop». Нормального русского аналого термина пока AFAIK нет; наименее кривой, пожалуй, — «for-цикл по коллекции». Появился начиная с С++11.

Синтаксис имеет вид:

```
for (TYPE i : abc) {
  // ...
}
```

- В качестве типа обычно выступает `auto`, `auto&` или `const auto&`.
- `abc` должен иметь соответствующий интерфейс, например, как у стандартных контейнеров — методы `begin()` и `end()`.

---

Подробности: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), [Что значит for(int x : vector)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/818882/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-forint-x-vector/818889#818889)